# Why is 32bit Firefox installed by default

Tags: firefox

When I install the latest FF it is 32bit by default, even on 64bit machines. Is there are reason for this?

Comment: If you mean from the main Firefox download page, I suppose they are not checking your system configuration. Not that big a deal since 32bit version will work OK. You can find all versions here: [Index of /pub/firefox/releases/](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/).